# The banner not showing with my id from adMob Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, admob, cordova-plugins

when i'll try run my application in my device with this code:

`ionic cordova build android`

It is generated an APK and I installed in my device. When i build with this code, the Ads works:

`showAd() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
     };
     this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
     this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
       .then(() => {
         // banner Ad is ready
         // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
       })
       .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }`

When I build with this other code, the Ads not show:

`showAd() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      id: 'MY-ID-FROM-ADMOB',
      isTesting: false,
      autoShow: true
     };
     this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
     this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
       .then(() => {
         // banner Ad is ready
         // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
       })
       .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }`

Someone help me, please...

Sorry if I wrote wrong something, my english is not very well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks suzan for share but it is not the solution. After 3 days I finally succeed publishing my app with ads.

1. I searched many solution, and in this post: [ionic-3-admob-free-not-displaying-ads-when-testing-is-false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797581/ionic-3-admob-free-not-displaying-ads-when-testing-is-false) Says that i needed to added my address on the payment page.
2. In the [cordova-plugin-admob-free](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free) site, i read that i needed added this code in my config.xml:

`<plugin name="cordova-admob-sdk" spec="~0.13.1">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.6.0" />
</plugin>`

3. I tested with this adID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111, this adId is found in [google test Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/test-ads) site, and worked!
4. When I was test with my adId showed a black rectangle istead of the Ads, i ignore it, because in [google Admob FAQ](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=pt-BR) says: When new apps are registered with AdMob,may taken a time for working. (summarizing)
5. When I published in Play store, the Ads are showing!!

Thanks for all =)

Comment: Can't we see Ads without publishing to play store ?? i have tested admob with test ad and its worked .

Comment: @ThisaraSubath We can't. You'll only see your ad when you publish your app.

This is did happen with me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it takes a while to display ads using the new adMob ad-ID.

And you should remove the `isTesting` from the admob config.

```
 showAd() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      id: 'MY-ID-FROM-ADMOB',
      autoShow: true
     };
     this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
     this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
       .then(() => {
         // banner Ad is ready
       })
       .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

It may take certain days or a day